Getting Error while loading Modelica System Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks.. Jacobian A contains non-linear components
simulating modelica model in ompython editor
from OMPython import ModelicaSystem

mod=ModelicaSystem("AppData/Roaming/.openmodelica/libraries/Modelica 4.0.0+maint.om/Fluid/Examples/ControlledTankSystem.mo",
"Modelica.Fluid.Examples.ControlledTankSystem.ControlledTanks",
["Modelica"],commandLineOptions="-d=aliasConflicts")`

ERROR:
Warning: Alias set with conflicting start values
 * Candidate: tank2.medium.T(start = tank2.T_start = 293.15, confidence number = 2)
 * Candidate: tank2.medium.state.T(start = 288.15, confidence number = 9)
 * Candidate: tank2.heatTransfer.states[1].T(start = 288.15, confidence number = 9)
=> Select value from tank2.medium.T(start = tank2.T_start = 293.15) for variable: tank2.medium.T

Error: Jacobian A contains non-linear components. This indicates a singular system or internal generation errors.**

How to solve the error?

According to https://libraries.openmodelica.org/branches/master/Modelica_4.0.0/Modelica_4.0.0.html the issue cannot be confirmed for latest build.
